# Can't override background on Button after pressing it in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, background, hover

I discovered that when using the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` event bindings on a Button to change it's color while the pointer hovers over it, it appeareantly does not work anymore after the first click on the Button itself.

Example script:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root=Tk()
        root.option_add('*Background','black')
        root.option_add('*Foreground','white')
        root.option_add('*Button.activeForeground','white')
        root.option_add('*Button.activeBackground','black')

        self.button=Button(root,text='Hello World')#,bg='black',fg='white')#,activebackground='white',activeforeground='black')
        self.button.pack(fill='both',expand=True,padx=10,pady=10)

        root.bind_class('Button','<Enter>',self.enter)
        root.bind_class('Button','<Leave>',self.leave)

        root.mainloop()
    def enter(self,event):
        print('entered')
        self.button.config(bg='red')
    def leave(self,event):
        print('left')
        self.button.config(bg='black')

if __name__=='__main__':
    App()
```

All I have tried so far:

- change the option_add variant to giving `bg` and so on in the initialization
- change bind_class to bind
- remove custom bg/fg/activebg/activefg completely (except in `self.enter` and `self.leave` for obvious reasons
- add `print` to see if `self.enter` and `self.leave` still get called (they do)

But nothing of that seems to work. When I did the first thing on the list the button actually didn't even changed back to the given bg after the click.

OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `root.bind_class(...)` to `self.button.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)`. and the same for `Leave`. I am not entirely sure how `bind_class` works or why it stops working after button click because all I have ever used was `bind` and `bind` works as needed.

Comment: @Mike - SMT As mentioned in my Question I've tried that already with no success.

Comment: You may have done something wrong as I can reproduce your problem with `bind_class` but when I simply use `bind` it works for me even after button press.

Comment: Well since i tried this multiple times I'm pretty sure I did not fail on all of them. So could it may be a problem which just I encounter on my PC? (Samsung Galaxy Book 12 Wifi)

Comment: The PC model itself is not important. What OS and Python version are you using. Also please test my examples below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue with `bind_class` however I have no idea why it stops working after button press. I have never used `bind_class` before.

That said simply using `bind` on the button directly works perfectly fine.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.option_add('*Background', 'black')
        root.option_add('*Foreground', 'white')
        root.option_add('*Button.activeForeground', 'white')
        root.option_add('*Button.activeBackground', 'black')

        self.button = Button(root, text='Hello World')
        self.button.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.button.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)

        root.mainloop()

    def enter(self, event):
        print('entered')
        self.button.config(bg='red')

    def leave(self, event):
        print('left')
        self.button.config(bg='black')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

Personally when building a class like this I like to have the class inherit from `Tk()` rather than defining root inside of the class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.option_add('*Background', 'black')
        self.option_add('*Foreground', 'white')
        self.option_add('*Button.activeForeground', 'white')
        self.option_add('*Button.activeBackground', 'black')

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Hello World')
        self.button.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.button.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)

    def enter(self, event):
        print('entered')
        self.button.config(bg='red')

    def leave(self, event):
        print('left')
        self.button.config(bg='black')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Well for your first example: I tried that version erlier as said in my question. And for the second one: The original application where this problem comes from the application class actually inherits from Tk as in your example.

Comment: @Nummer_42O You said `change bind_class to bind` but did you also change the parameters? Can you provide an example where you used `bind()`?

Comment: First example works in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.1.

Comment: @Mike - SMT For sure I changed parameters. It would have thrown an TclError with the ```bind_class``` parameters since ```'Button'``` isn't an valid event. I'm sorry if that sounds cocky but I ain't stupid. For the example it just looked exactly like yours (there isn't much which could be different to be honesz). I can't explain to myself why that didn't worked either. Maybe I messed up somewhere completely else. Maybe last time when I had a look at ```tkinter.__init__```... In this case it might be useful to reinstall it...

Comment: @Nummer_42O if running my example does not work for you then something must be wrong. I would try a clean install on the latest version. No one said you were stupid but stuff happens. All to often do people stare at their code for hours just to find out they had a typo or a comma out of place or something small like that. So without seeing an example of you using `bind()` I have to speculate on what might be wrong. That is why I asked for you to show an example.

Comment: Well I can't give you that example because I've overwritten it already with other tests I mare on that code. But today after retrying it it works. It seems like something went wrong with my computer there and all it needed was a restart. I still don't get how this is possible or how this could even happen but it did... maybe I should take a look at whats wrong with my pc... anyways, thank you.

Comment: @Nummer_42O ah Windows. When in doubt reboot. Classic fix. :D

Comment: It's kinda sad that this is true tbh... I really really really need to settle over to Linux or at least get it as a secondary launchable OS...